# Meteor: cant insert and pull from database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm following along with the meteor tutorial (making a few minor changes here and there) and when it comes to inserting and pulling from the database I don't seem to be having much luck.

Here is my html file:

```
<head>
  <title>test server</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>test server</h1>
        <div class="loginButton">{{ >loginButtons}}</div>
    </header>
    {{#if currentUser}}
        <nav>
            <h1>Jobs</h1>
            <form class="new-job">
                <input type="text" name="job" placeholder="Type to enter new job">
            </form>
            <ul>
                {{#each jobs}}
                    {{> job}}
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>
        </main>
    {{/if}}
</body>

<template name="job">
    <li>{{name}}</li>
</template>
```

and my javascript file:

```
Jobs = new Mongo.Collection("jobs");

if (Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.publish("jobs", function(){
        return Jobs.find()
    })
}

if (Meteor.isClient){
    Meteor.subscribe("jobs");

    Template.body.helpers({
        jobs: function(){
            return Jobs.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}); 
        }
    });

    Template.body.events({
        "submit .new-job": function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            var name = event.target.job.value;

            Meteor.call("addJob", name);

            event.target.job.value = "";
        }
    })

    Accounts.ui.config({
        passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
    });
}

Meteor.methods({
    addJob: function(name){
        if (! Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
        }

        Jobs.insert({
            name: name,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            owner: Meteor.userId(),
            username: Meteor.user().username
        });
    }
})
```

I haven't made any changes to the database (using the one preinstalled with meteor)

The problem is when I fill in the form and submit, nothing gets stored in the collection. I verify this by taking a look at the db itself and nothing is there.

Furthermore, I manually inserted a document into the collection using the mongo shell (`db.jobs.insert({ name: test, createdAt: new Date()});`), and can verify that the document exists in the collection. However, it does not appear on the website within the unordered list.

I have removed the `insecure` and `autopublish` packages if that makes a difference

What is wrong with my code that is preventing the client/server from talking to the database?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your browser console or server?

Comment: In the browser console I see this `Error invoking Method 'addJob': Method not found [404]` which I dont understand because that is part of the meteor methods defined at the bottom of the JS file

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer... so another comment... yay! Try hoisting your call to `Meteor.methods` up above your server / client logic. Right after you declare your `Jobs` collection. I think that will help, normally this code would be broken out into multiple files that would help it flow a little more smoothly.

Comment: This exact code works for me. Make sure you've removed insecure and autopublish and you've added accounts-password and accounts-ui and also make sure there is no other pieces of code lying around that messes up with this.

Comment: @Shaded I've tried hoisting meteor methods manually but the app still cant find the addJob method

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy I've ensured that insecure and autopublish are removed. the accounts packages are also installed because I can actually log in to the site with no problem. Problem still persists

Comment: What's your meteor version? I created a blank meteor project, added accounts packages, removed autopublish/insecure, replaced the html and js files with exactly this content, nothing more, nothing less, and it just works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up recreating the project and everything worked from that point on.

With the new project I placed all files in the root directory which appeared to fix the problem, whereas before I had things split up into /client and /server directories